# How did old mobile phones amplify signals lower than the noise floor?

Tags: amplifier, noise, gsm, signal-to-noise

[image: RxLevel of old Nokia mobile phone]

[image: Noise Floor of an electronic device]

In the early days of GSM in around 2000 when the network was still not fully deployed, it was common for me to receive very low signal, even sometimes ***No Signal*** due to out of network.

I used to use a Nokia phone which was equipped with a built in NetMonitor so sometimes I checked the signal level in certain areas I visited. Sometimes I got -80 dBm, -90 dBm, or  even -100 dBm. Nowadays I never meet again such that area.

As shown in the picture 1, the RxLevel sometimes is -101 dBm. This RxLevel is lower than the noise floor of electronic devices, which is around -90 to -80 dBm.

With this noise floor and the RxLevel = -101 dBm, the signal to noise ratio (SNR) is less than 1. As we see in picture 2, the Agilent measurement result,
a signal below the noise floor can't be measured.

How can the electronic equipment operate with such a low signal? How could the mobile phone amplify a signal that is lower than the noise floor? Bear in mind that the shown RxLevel is the received signal in the mobile phone, not the received signal on the antenna.

Comment: A 200kHz(GSM) wide channel has a thermal noise power of around -120dBm, significantly smaller than -85dBm.

Comment: @Linkyyy Where did you get the info? Noise floor is not related to GSM, but related to physical conductor property.

Comment: But what's that -85dBm graph a measurement of though - it's the noise floor of a random spectrum analyser with no context. The phones receiver will have its own characteristics.

Comment: @TomCarpenter noise floor is thermal noise of a conductor. It is a physical limitation of any conductor, unless the conductor is super conductor. But here, we clearly are not talking about super conductor.

Comment: I know what the noise floor is, and it's not just to do with thermal noise. My point is each device has electronic circuitry with different sources of noise. Each amplifier will inherantly add noise, power supplies will add noise, resistors will add thermal noise. Just because the noise floor of that particular model of spectrum analyser is -85dBm doesn't mean that every device has the same noise floor.

Comment: See the [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise#Noise_power_in_decibels). A 200kHz bandwidth GSM channel would see on the order of -121dBm thermal noise at 300K.

Comment: To improve the noise floor on that analyzer, reduce its resolution BW (RBW) currently set to 10kHz, see bottom left. I have a spectrum analyzer whose RBW goes down to 3 Hz. Much lower noise, but takes an age to make a plot. (And it won't do GHz)

Comment: @TomCarpenter, please learn again about noise power spectral density. Your understanding is wrong about it.

Comment: @AirCraftLover no, you're the one totally out of line here, as I'm the sixth expert to tell you... Your understanding is wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, which part I was totally wrong? About the noise power? As far as my understanding, the power noise is average value. If you really think you know the answer, why don't you just write your answer so I can accept?

Comment: @user_1818839, I have no idea that it will affect the measurement. Long ago I used to do frequency scanning before installing microwave, especially for high capacity such as SDH and certain PCM in a crowded area.

Comment: @AirCraftLover you're wrong about the noise floor bring something at a fixed -85 dB, and since if you understand what that would mean, you couldn't come to that conclusion, probably about some more things. Luckily, I don't need to write that in an answer - Tom Carpenter had explained this to you here in a comment, and Neil has clarified it in his answer already.

Comment: For comparison, GPS is actually below noise floor of most receivers on Earth. It uses spread spectrum [process gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_gain) to separate the signal from the noise.

Comment: @jpa, this is something new to me. I just clicked your link, there is mentioned about baseband frequency. I remember a BTS machine from Finland, there is module called baseband module. It is probably the answer.

Comment: @AirCraftLover The noise floor is a fundamental property of a conductor the same way that height is a fundamental property of a person. Every person has one, but that doesn't mean that every person has the *same* one.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield, yes, of course. Some mentioned about *power density*, which seems like there is different explanation I got between from here and from some I got from Youtube. I used to do frequency scanning for SDH link and PDH for crowded location such as in the downtown. I forgot the detail, but mostly closed to -90dBm, maybe around -88dBm. I was wondering that measurement we did could be have been wrong and inaccurate, even the measurement result not affect the result.

Answer (score 17):

> As shown in the picture 1, the RxLevel sometimes is -101 dBm. This RxLevel is lower than the noise floor of electronic devices, which is around -90 to -80 dBm.

Well there's your problem, the assertion that 'electronic devices' have a noise floor of -90 to -80 dBm.

The graph from the wikipedia article you quote<sup>1</sup> shows **a** noise floor of -85 dBm in a 10 kHz (40dBHz (noise bandwidth is power remember, so it's 10log10, not 20log10)) resolution bandwidth, ie -125 dBm/Hz (give or take 2.5dB for peak log), for some random unspecified thing it's connected to. Although spectrum analysers generally have an atrocious noise figure, this is so high that it's probably measuring a high gain amplifier generating quite a high level of noise at its output, rather than its own input noise.

The fundamental physics 'rules of the universe' lower limit for noise is -174 dBm/Hz, at room temperature. All systems will exhibit at least this.

Any practical receiver will have a higher noise floor than the fundamental limit. A good receiver may be able limit that degradation to a dB or so.

A GSM signal has a bandwidth of 200 kHz, or 53dBHz, which gives a fundamental noise floor of -121dBm in the GSM channel. IIRC, GSM receivers need to have a better floor than -118dBm to be approved for use on the network (someone who knows their stuff please correct me?), and are generally a bit better.

With a GSM signal power of -101dBm, the SNR could approach 20dB, and will be substantially better than 15dB, plenty for excellent reception.

1 - that's a very poor article. I'll look at the talk, and see whether it can be improved without a rewrite.

Comment: What do you think about baseband/unspread bandwidth as citied by @jpa in his/her commend below my post. I remember a BTS machine by a Finnish company, there is module called baseband module. It was exist with 900/1800MHz. It is related on a very top of the BTS shelf. Is it related?

Comment: @AirCraftLover Processing gain seems magical until you realise it's another way of accounting for power. Frequency and time are the two common bases to project signal energy onto, and then frequency naturally gives rise to the concept of noise bandwidth. You can also project onto orthogonal 'sequencies', typically called spreading at the transmitter and despreading at the receiver. You can generalise noise bandwidth slightly to work with these. Even if you call it averaging or correlation when you can, the maths works the same, and the noise drops while the signal doesn't, improving SNR.

Comment: So, based on your understanding, what is the allowed minimum received signal level (RxLevel) and what bandwidth a system may received and proceed? I am curious about how the Voyager-1 and Voyager-2's signals received and proceed by NASA from the brink of our galaxy, which I guess the signals are very weak.

Comment: @AirCraftLover The Shannon-Hartley theorem (1) says that with suitable source coding, you can transmit 1 bit per Hz bandwidth even with a 0dB SNR in the channel without error. We still don't know how to code a source that well, though both Turbo (2) codes and Low Density Parity Check (3) codes can get within about 1dB of Shannon. LNAs can get to 1dB noise figure comfortably. There's a lot of info out there, wikipedia 1, 2 and 3. The Voyagers, they crank up transmit power, use good source coding, reduce the data rate, use large antennas on earth, until they hit Shannon.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Can you please explain what answer *would* satisfy you? It seems you're looking for something and not finding it. Come up with an answer you'd like, and then look carefully for why it's wrong :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, about the received signal, I once asked the RF guys who did RF planning for the GSM networks. According to him, the accepted RxLevel should not be less than -90dBm. According to him, the normal operation should be around -70dBm. Then there is another explanation here that seems like mismatch to the answer I heard. So, I must be sure that the answer in here is correct. About spectral density, I have searched it in Youtube and seems there is still not so convincing answer here as the explanation in Youtube said the the spectral density is accumulated.

Comment: @Neil_UK, do you think that your explanation is inline with the explanation here: https://youtu.be/ujce9AzrqdY ? He put 1MHz band with measurement around -77dBm. According to his explanation, the actual level is -77dBm-(10 log(1MHz))=-77dBm-60dB=-57dBm. With the same logic, the RxLevel of the GSM, the -101dBm would be -101dBm-(10 log(200kHz)dB)=-101dBm-53dB=-154dBm. This is different than your explanation.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, I added another comment to the comment owner as I didn't satisfied.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Watch that youtube clip again and do the sums properly. When he controlled the inputs of the SA, first to put the input atten on manual to get 0 dB, then at 5 minutes in to switch the preamplifier on (preamplifier === LNA (low noise amplifier)), he got -167 dBm/Hz, quite respectable given the theoretical best of -174 he could have got, but still not as good as a GSM phone receiver could be. Everything he did on that clip aligns perfectly with my explanation, the differences are the particulars of how he set the spectrum analyser, and the actual numbers used for bandwidth etc.

Comment: @AirCraftLover If you're wondering why I still assert that a mobile phone receiver should do better on noise floor than a spectrum analyser, it's because they are built and optimised for different purposes. A phone has "Just One Job (tm)" which is to dig a specific signal frequency and bandwidth out of the noise. A spectrum analyser OTOH has to cover a wide bandwidth, at bandwidths from Hz to multi-MHz, with flatness from MHz to GHz, with low distortion, and be quite robust against somebody keying a transmitter into it. These things cost, and one of the costs is noise figure.

Comment: What do you think about the LoRa reception in this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adhWIo-7gr4) video? He used 902MHz, 20dBm Tx power, and he can reached until 200km long. He even mentioned that LoRa can reach 700km if it is used for satellite communication. The detail of his device there is in his description. With 200km, its free space path loss (FSPL) is 137.57dB. Seems like magic.

Comment: There is another magic calculation he made here (https://youtu.be/hMOwbNUpDQA?t=556), it even can reach 1300km.

Comment: Before I wrote this question, I Googled about LoRa antenna sensitivity, and I got explanation like this: "LoRa receivers are able to lock on to the frequency chirps received, offering a sensitivity of the order of −130 dBm" (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5038744/#:~:text=LoRa%20receivers%20are%20able%20to,dBm%20%5B19%2C20%5D.) . I have to admit that my understanding about this topic is seems like still far from approaching.

Answer (score 6):

Not a full answer, but some general ideas.

I will suppose digital signal in "logic level". The reasoning could be extended to analog signals, but it's a bit more complicated.

Let's suppose each bit is (ideally) represented by either 0V or 5V.
If your noise is always less than 2.5V, then you can always be 100% sure about the value of the bit.

Now let's suppose noise up to 4V. If you measure something <1V, you are sure it is supposed to be a 0, it is above 4V, you are sure it is supposed to be a 1. In between, you are unsure (but usually, the nearer you are to 5V, the more likely it is that it is supposed to be a 1).

So, for example, if you decide that each bit is repeated 10 times, then you can average the values, and be quite sure about the result (supposing noise is independent, so it cancels out in the average).

Now suppose you have a very high gaussian noise, for example 100V standard deviation with no time correlation (ie the value of the added noise is independent on each measurement).

Your 5V signal is well below the noise level.
But if your signal is slow enough, you can make multiple measurements. If measurements are independent, then the noise of the average has a standard deviation of 1/sqrt(N), where N is the number of measurements. So if you take 100 measurements, the noise on the average is divided by 10, so 10V (still not enough). If you take 10,000 measurements, the noise is divided by 100, so you have 1V of noise - this time, you clearly see your 5V signal.

So, there is no issue with a signal below noise level: you just have to average it over a long enough duration to retrieve it (which means, you are quite limited in the amount of data you can transmit).

To give you a completely different example: if you try to measure the sea level, in order to sea how it changes due to global warming, you are looking into a signal in the centimeter range, yet your noise (waves and tides) is several meters. It's still done without problem, simply by averaging over several weeks.

Comment: How did you still talk 2.5V while the RxLevel is around -100dBm? -100dBm is 0.1pico watt.

Comment: This is just an example with an "easy" situation (simple logic signals, usual voltages, ...) to show you that some "averaging" is all it takes to get a signal "lost" in noise. In the case of "radio" communication, the "averaging" becomes more complicated (and I have no idea how it is done), but the main idea remains the same : each measurement carries some very small amount of information, so if you do enough measurements, you can retrieve some useful information

Comment: @AirCraftLover This answer simplifies things, since your question is based on a premise that breaks down even in this simple example :) So getting simple things right is important. You can scale this answer to any level you want. Even levels *below* the theoretical limit - that's what averaging is good for. Ask anyone working with radiotelescope signals :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, "*Ask anyone working with radio telescope signals,*" actually, it was on my mind but hard for me to phrase it. I was wonder how the signal frpm Voyager1 & Voyager2 that travel to the brink of our Galaxy but the the signal they transmit to the earth still proceed-able. But I don't have any idea about what is the signal level received in Earth Station. Then I remember when around 2 decades ago I used to used Nokia with NetMonitor installed on it which I used to check the received signal when I was surveying location for microwave transmission link.

Comment: The signals from Voyager 1 or 2 have traveled nowhere close to the brink of our galaxy.